# How to get a DateDiff-Value in milliseconds in VBA (Excel)?

Tags: vba, excel, datediff

I need to calculate the difference between two timestamps in milliseconds.
Unfortunately, the DateDiff-function of VBA does not offer this precision.
Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You could use the method described [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=2292) as follows:-

Create a new class module called `StopWatch`
Put the following code in the `StopWatch` class module:

```
Private mlngStart As Long
Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Public Sub StartTimer()
    mlngStart = GetTickCount
End Sub

Public Function EndTimer() As Long
    EndTimer = (GetTickCount - mlngStart)
End Function
```

You use the code as follows:

```
Dim sw as StopWatch
Set sw = New StopWatch
sw.StartTimer

' Do whatever you want to time here

Debug.Print "That took: " & sw.EndTimer & "milliseconds"
```

Other methods describe use of the VBA Timer function but this is only accurate to one hundredth of a second (centisecond).

Comment: Note that while `GetTickCount` resolves in millseconds, it has a accuracy of about 16ms [see this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Just a question: how can this calculate the time difference between 2 values stored in excel?

Comment: The question is about how to calculate the differences between two timestamps in VBA

Comment: I.e. Excel is purely coincidental.

Comment: This does NOT answer the OP's question AT ALL.

Comment: It does indeed take a step back and assumes that the time between two _events_ is what is important, rather than two already provided timestamps, but it appears that that was what the OP wanted to do, and that's why the answer is accepted. If anything, the question should be edited to reflect what the OP really wanted.

Answer (score 16):

If you just need time elapsed in Centiseconds then you don't need the TickCount API. You can just use the VBA.Timer Method which is present in all Office products.

```
Public Sub TestHarness()
    Dim fTimeStart As Single
    Dim fTimeEnd As Single
    fTimeStart = Timer
    SomeProcedure
    fTimeEnd = Timer
    Debug.Print Format$((fTimeEnd - fTimeStart) * 100!, "0.00 "" Centiseconds Elapsed""")
End Sub

Public Sub SomeProcedure()
    Dim i As Long, r As Double
    For i = 0& To 10000000
        r = Rnd
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If `Timer()` precision is enough then you can just create timestamp by combining date and time with milliseconds:

```vb
Function Now2() As Date

    Now2 = Date + CDate(Timer / 86400)

End Function
```

To calculate the difference between two timestamps in milliseconds you may subtract them:

```vb
Sub test()

    Dim start As Date
    Dim finish As Date
    Dim i As Long

    start = Now2
    For i = 0 To 100000000
    Next
    finish = Now2
    Debug.Print (finish - start) & " days"
    Debug.Print (finish - start) * 86400 & " sec"
    Debug.Print (finish - start) * 86400 * 1000 & " msec"

End Sub
```

Actual precision of that method is about 8 msec (BTW `GetTickCount` is even worse - 16 msec) for me.

Answer (score 1):

GetTickCount and Performance Counter are required if you want to go for micro seconds..
For millisenconds you can just use some thing like this..

```
'at the bigining of the module
Private Type SYSTEMTIME  
        wYear As Integer  
        wMonth As Integer  
        wDayOfWeek As Integer  
        wDay As Integer  
        wHour As Integer  
        wMinute As Integer  
        wSecond As Integer  
        wMilliseconds As Integer  
End Type  

Private Declare Sub GetLocalTime Lib "kernel32" (lpSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME)  


'In the Function where you need find diff
Dim sSysTime As SYSTEMTIME
Dim iStartSec As Long, iCurrentSec As Long    

GetLocalTime sSysTime
iStartSec = CLng(sSysTime.wSecond) * 1000 + sSysTime.wMilliseconds
'do your stuff spending few milliseconds
GetLocalTime sSysTime ' get the new time
iCurrentSec=CLng(sSysTime.wSecond) * 1000 + sSysTime.wMilliseconds
'Different between iStartSec and iCurrentSec will give you diff in MilliSecs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `=NOW()` formula calcilated in cell:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheet1

 ws.Range("a1").formula = "=now()"
 ws.Range("a1").numberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy h:mm:ss.000"
 Application.Wait Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
 ws.Range("a2").formula = "=now()"
 ws.Range("a2").numberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy h:mm:ss.000"
 ws.Range("a3").formula = "=a2-a1"
 ws.Range("a3").numberFormat = "h:mm:ss.000"
 var diff as double
 diff = ws.Range("a3")
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies to wake up this old post, but I got an answer:
Write a function for Millisecond like this:

```
Public Function TimeInMS() As String
TimeInMS = Strings.Format(Now, "HH:nn:ss") & "." & Strings.Right(Strings.Format(Timer, "#0.00"), 2) 
End Function
```

Use this function in your sub:

```
Sub DisplayMS()
On Error Resume Next
Cancel = True
Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = TimeInMS()
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Besides the Method described by AdamRalph (`GetTickCount()`), you can do this:

- Using the `QueryPerformanceCounter()` and `QueryPerformanceFrequency()` API Functions
  [How do you test running time of VBA code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198409/how-do-you-test-running-time-of-vba-code)
- or, for environments without access to the Win32 API (like VBScript), this:
  http://ccrp.mvps.org/ (check the download section for the "High-Performance Timer" installable COM objects. They're free.)

Comment: Is there any pro or con to using QPC instead of Tickcount?

Comment: Using QueryPerformanceCounter() requires considerably more code. Maybe it's useful if you are already dealing with perf counters in your code. I just wanted to mention the alternative, I don't think the results are any different. I suspect it boils down to GetTickCount() internally anyway. :)