# Time Calculation in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, time, excel-2003

I am getting time as `23300000`  i.e. `hhMMssmm` format as string
and I want to calculate difference of such two values.

Here hh is hours, MM is minutes, ss is seconds, and mm is 60th of second.
Using VBA for Excel 2003

Comment: how are you planning to calculate the difference between a date that goes over the next day? Ie. 23:30 and 1:30 the next day?

Comment: No the values will be of same day. so 1:30 will never be there.
It will always maximum as  `24000000`

Comment: well, you need some if-else logic for this to work, specially the `mm` part. why dont you show us what you have tried and tell what does not work and then we can help you

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939230/how-to-get-a-datediff-value-in-milliseconds-in-vba-excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **UDF** will return the absolute value of the difference in *seconds*

```
Public Function tDiff(s1 As String, s2 As String) As Double
'
'   calculates the absolute value of the differences
'   returns the answer in seconds
'
    Dim hrs As Double, mins As Double, secs As Double, sixt As Double
    Dim tVal1 As Double, tVal2 As Double

    hrs = CDbl(Mid(s1, 1, 2)) * 60 * 60
    mins = CDbl(Mid(s1, 3, 2)) * 60
    secs = CDbl(Mid(s1, 5, 2))
    sixt = CDbl(Mid(s1, 7, 2)) / 60
    tVal1 = hrs + mins + secs + sixt

    hrs = CDbl(Mid(s2, 1, 2)) * 60 * 60
    mins = CDbl(Mid(s2, 3, 2)) * 60
    secs = CDbl(Mid(s2, 5, 2))
    sixt = CDbl(Mid(s2, 7, 2)) / 60
    tVal2 = hrs + mins + secs + sixt

    If tVal1 > tVal2 Then
        tDiff = tVal1 - tVal2
    Else
        tDiff = tVal2 - tVal1
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I am suspecting the OP would like the returned value to also be a string in the same format as the input one ;)

Comment: @mehow I was uncertain of the form or format of the result.  I posted one option.  If *Rohit* would like another format, I will update my answer to suit.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim ms1 As Double
    Dim ms2 As Double

    ms1 = ToSeconds(23142700)
    ms2 = ToSeconds(23311500)

    Debug.Print "Difference between dates in seconds: " & ms2 - ms1
End Sub


Public Function ToSeconds(number As Long) As Double
    Dim hh As Long
    Dim mm As Long
    Dim ss As Long
    Dim ms As Long

    ms = (number Mod (100 ^ 1)) / (100 ^ 0)
    ss = (number Mod (100 ^ 2) - ms) / (100 ^ 1)
    mm = (number Mod (100 ^ 3) - ss * (100 ^ 1) - ms) / (100 ^ 2)
    hh = (number Mod (100 ^ 4) - mm * (100 ^ 2) - ss * (100 ^ 1) - ms) / (100 ^ 3)

    ToSeconds = ms * 1 / 60 + ss + mm * 60 + hh * 60 * 60
End Function
```

The ToSeconds() function converts your number to seconds, and you can do your calculations based on that.

Comment: Fair enough - edited the function to return the number of seconds passed since midnight instead.

Answer (score 0):

While this solution may not be as short as the others, I believe it is very easy to understand. Not everything here may be necessary, but you may find some of it useful in the future.

The `run` sub routine allows you to run the `test` function with your specified values.
The `test` function tests the `timeDiff` & `timeSum` logic.
The `timeDiff` function finds the time-difference between `t1` and `t0`.
The `timeSum` function finds the time-sum of `t1` and `t0`.
The `asDuration` function removes the AM/PM suffix from a time value.
The `asMilitary` function converts 12-hour format to 24 hour-format.
The `concat` function I created to more easily concatenate strings.

```
Sub Main() 'Run Test
    MsgBox Test("0:29:0", "23:30:0")
End Sub

Function Test(startT As Date, endT As Date) 'Test timeDiff & timeSum logic
    Dim nextShift As Date, prevShift As Date, hours As Date

    hours = timeDiff(endT, startT)
    prevShift = timeDiff(startT, "0:30:0")
    nextShift = timeSum("0:30:0", endT)        

    Test = concat("Start -", startT, "", "End - ", endT, "", "Duration -", asDuration(hours), "", "Next Shift: ", nextShift, "", "Prev Shift: ", prevShift)
End Function


Function timeDiff(t1 As Date, t0 As Date) As Date 'Return Time1 minus Time0
    Dim units(0 To 2) As String

    units(0) = Hour(t1) - Hour(t0)
    units(1) = Minute(t1) - Minute(t0)
    units(2) = Second(t1) - Second(t0)

    If units(2) < 0 Then
        units(2) = units(2) + 60
        units(1) = units(1) - 1
    End If

    If units(1) < 0 Then
        units(1) = units(1) + 60
        units(0) = units(0) - 1
    End If

    units(0) = IIf(units(0) < 0, units(0) + 24, units(0))
    timeDiff = Join(units, ":")
End Function


Function timeSum(t1 As Date, t0 As Date) As Date 'Return Time1 plus Time0
    Dim units(0 To 2) As String

    units(0) = Hour(t1) + Hour(t0)
    units(1) = Minute(t1) + Minute(t0)
    units(2) = Second(t1) + Second(t0)

    If units(2) >= 60 Then
        units(2) = units(2) Mod 60
        units(1) = units(1) + 1
    End If

    If units(1) >= 60 Then
        units(1) = units(1) Mod 60
        units(0) = units(0) + 1
    End If

    units(0) = IIf(units(0) >= 24, units(0) Mod 24, units(0))
    timeSum = Join(units, ":")
End Function


Function asDuration(time As Date) As String 'Display as duration; Remove AM/PM suffix from time
    time = asMilitary(time)
    asDuration = Left(time, Len(time))
End Function


Function asMilitary(time As Date) As String 'Convert 12-hour format to 24-hour-format
    asMilitary = Hour(time) & ":" & Minute(time) & ":" & Second(time)
End Function


Function concat(ParamArray var() As Variant) As String 'Return arguments of function call concatenated as a single string
    For Each elem In var()
        concat = IIf(elem <> "", concat & elem & " ", concat & vbNewLine)
    Next
End Function
```