# I can't use datediff vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

Example input:

```
date1 = "2015-03-23 07:06:17.855000"
date2 = "2015-03-23 07:06:17.870000"
```

When I use

```
ans = datediff("s", date1, date2)
```

It produces the error: `type mismatch`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like you've got a successful answer yet, so here's a possibility.

```
Dim t() as string
Dim d1 as long
Dim d2 as long

date1 = "2015-03-23 07:06:17.855000"
date2 = "2015-03-23 07:06:17.870000"
t = split(date1, ".")   'use the "." to split off the miliseconds
d1 = clng(t(2))         'grab the milliseconds, convert it to long
t = split(date2, ".")   'use the "." to split off the miliseconds from the other date
d2 = clng(t(2))         'grab the milliseconds, convert it to long

msgbox "Difference in milliseconds: " & cstr(d2-d1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert dates stored as a string to date data type by using `CDate("string_date")`:

```
Dim date1 As String, date2 As String, ans As Long

date1 = "2015-03-23 07:06:17.855000"
date2 = "2015-03-23 07:06:17.870000"
ans = datediff("s", CDate(Left(date1, Len(date1)-7)), CDate(Left(date2, Len(date2)-7)))
'returns 0, because both date and parts are the same!
```

The smallest unit of [DateDiff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function is a second.

Comment: I see it now. DateDiff function can return time difference in seconds, but the real difference is in miliseconds. `DateDiff` function can't compare it, because the smallest unit is a second. When you pass date parameter this way: `CDate(Left(date1, Len(date1)-7)` it will execute without errors.

Comment: @Maciej Los ans may have to be long, and your brackets are out of count, 7-"(" and only 6-")"

Comment: [How to get a DateDiff-Value in milliseconds in VBA (Excel)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939230/how-to-get-a-datediff-value-in-milliseconds-in-vba-excel)

Comment: @Davesexcel, Interesting question and answers, but - as i mentioned - it's impossible to get miliseconds via DateDiff function.

Comment: @Maciej Los-I didn't ask a question, I supplied a link to the Milli-seconds question and explained to you that your code does not have enough closing brackets and that "ans" should be long

Comment: @Davesexcel, i know that you aren't a questioner. Answer has been updated.