# Can I get VBA equivalent of DateTime.Now.Ticks?

Tags: vba, excel

In VB within .NET I can use `DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x")` to get a string ready for a multipart form boundary e.g. `8d4b7556f42792c`

I'm trying to get the same thing in VBA within Excel.

In Excel VBA I can use `DateTime.Now` to get now in the format: 19/06/2017 20:54

That's not really helpful though, I need to convert it to string of ticks and then convert to hexadecimal. So far I've found that `HEX(DateTime.Now)` just gives me a four char return like `A79A` which is not what I need.

CAN I get ticks from `DateTime.Now` ?!

EDIT: I've just found this trick to get some sort of Tick Count:

```
Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long
MsgBox (GetTickCount())
```

And that gives me a negative double or so... that might do for what I need, but is it TickCount as in NOW?

Comment: DateTime in VBA? You can use Date.

Comment: Maciej - yeah I just tried `MsgBox Now` without the `DateTime` and it worked. But it also works with it and gives me the intellisense list of possible methods etc. ?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939230/how-to-get-a-datediff-value-in-milliseconds-in-vba-excel)

Comment: @MaciejLos `DateTime` is the name of the module; the fully qualified name is `VBA.DateTime.Now`, where `VBA` is the library, `DateTime` is the module, and `Now` is a property getter that returns a `Date` value. Fully qualifying member calls is always a good idea.

Comment: Why not just use a hard-coded value?

Comment: can ´t use ´timer ´ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excel is irrelevant, `DateTime` is a module from the `VBA` standard library, which is always referenced in any VBA project, regardless of the host.

A `Date` in VBA is essentially a `Double` where the integer part is the number of days since December 30, 1899:

```
?CDate(1)
12/31/1899
```

The decimal part represents the *time* part of that value, i.e. one hour is 1/24th, one minute is 1/60th of that, one second is 1/60th of that, and one millisecond would be 1/1000th of that...

You should read up on `GetTickCount` on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408(v=vs.85).aspx) before using it:

> *The elapsed time is stored as a DWORD value. Therefore, the time will wrap around to zero if the system is run continuously for 49.7 days. To avoid this problem, use the GetTickCount64 function. Otherwise, check for an overflow condition when comparing times.*

If you're getting a negative tick count, it means your system has been up for quite a while and overflowed the `DWORD` size, 32 bits (i.e. 2<sup>31</sup>-1, or 2,147,483,647)

---

Instead of using `GetTickCount` and working with more or less meaningless "ticks" (being relative to system uptime [and only precise to ~15ms]), why not work with the actual system time and get actual milliseconds?

Define a [`SYSTEMTIME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950(v=vs.85).aspx) struct:

```
Private Type SYSTEMTIME
    wYear As Integer
    wMonth As Integer
    wDayOfWeek As Integer
    wDay As Integer
    wHour As Integer
    wMinute As Integer
    wSecond As Integer
    wMilliseconds As Integer
End Type
```

Declare the [`GetSystemTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724390(v=vs.85).aspx) procedure:

```
Private Declare Sub GetSystemTime Lib "Kernel32" (ByRef lpSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME)
```

Call it by passing a `SYSTEMTIME` value by reference:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim t As SYSTEMTIME
    GetSystemTime t
    Debug.Print t.wYear, t.wMonth, t.wDay, t.wHour, t.wMinute, t.wSecond, t.wMilliseconds
End Sub
```

The retrieved value will be UTC time, so if you need local time, apply the appropriate offset.