# Excel vba GetPrivateProfileString working 2007, but not 2010

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code declared:

```
Private Declare Function GetPrivateProfileString Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetPrivateProfileStringA" (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, ByVal lpKeyName As Any, ByVal lpDefault As String, ByVal lpReturnedString As String, ByVal nSize As Long, ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long
```

And i have a function to access it as follows:

```
Private Function ReadIniFileString(ByVal Sect As String, ByVal Keyname As String) As   String
Dim Worked As Long
Dim RetStr As String * 128
Dim StrSize As Long
Dim iNoOfCharInIni As Long
Dim sIniString As String
Dim sProfileString As String

iNoOfCharInIni = 0
sIniString = ""
If Sect = "" Or Keyname = "" Then
   MsgBox "Section Or Key To Read Not Specified !!!", vbExclamation, "INI"
Else
   sProfileString = ""
RetStr = Space(128)
StrSize = Len(RetStr)
Worked = GetPrivateProfileString(Sect, Keyname, "", RetStr, StrSize, IniFileName)
   If Worked Then
      iNoOfCharInIni = Worked
      sIniString = Left$(RetStr, Worked)
   End If
 End If
ReadIniFileString = sIniString
End Function
```

This works under 2007, but i get an error on Excel 2010 at the:

```
Worked = GetPrivateProfileString(Sect, Keyname, "", RetStr, StrSize, IniFileName)
```

i get an "Can't find sub or function error" I have seen on the web that i should be able to fix this via declaring the function at PtrSafe, and returning a LongPtr. I've done that but get the same results!

Any help please!

Thanks so much!

Russ

Comment: Have you tried to remove `private` from your declaration?

Answer (score 3):

To make this work in a 64 bit version of Excell you need to add the PtrSafe Attribute to the function Declaration like so:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function GetPrivateProfileString Lib "kernel32" Alias...
```

Comment: I can confirm that this solution does in fact work for this function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say whether Excel 2010 is 32 bits or 64. I'm not sure what would happen if a VBA module running in a 64 bit instance of Excel would do if it tried to call a 32 bit routine, and kernel32.dll is a 32 bit library. Since GetPrivatePorfileString is deprecated, I suspect it didn't get ported to the 64 bit counterpart of kernel32.dll.

Comment: This function declaration can be updated to 64 bits as explained here for example : http://dominogavin.blogspot.fr/2012/02/adjusting-our-word-vba-macros-for.html

Answer (score -1):

This is the correct code. I hope works!

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetProfileString Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetProfileStringA" ( _
    ByVal lpAppName As String, _
    ByVal lpKeyName As String, _
    ByVal lpDefault As String, _
    ByVal lpReturnedString As String, _
    ByVal nSize As Long) As Long
```

Comment: Nothing new as answer, but forgetting the last argument `lpFilename` :-;