# Alternate to Replace function cell by cell - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a few dozen columns with hundreds of rows for each. One of the subs that I am calling goes and modifies the data of the cells after it comes in from an XML hosted on the web. The current method works, but it tends to get a bit slow since it does the changes cell by cell. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub fixEnt(listCol As ListColumn) 'fixes the HTML/XML entities
    Dim rng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = listCol.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        For Each areaItem In rng.Areas 'iterate over the arrays in the Areas array
            For Each cell In areaItem 'iterate over the values in the Item array
                cell.Value = decodeEnt(cell.Value)
            Next
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

which calls on decodeEnt:

```
Private Function decodeEnt(cellVal As String) As String

    Dim tempStr$ 'holds new value after replace
    tempStr = Replace(cellVal, "&#34;", Chr(34)) 'Chr(34) is a "
    tempStr = Replace(tempStr, "&#39;", "'")
    tempStr = Replace(tempStr, "&#38;", "&")
    tempStr = Replace(tempStr, "&#60;", "<")
    tempStr = Replace(tempStr, "&#62;", ">")
    tempStr = Replace(tempStr, "&#160;", " ")
    tempStr = Replace(tempStr, "&#35;", "#")
    tempStr = Replace(tempStr, "&nbsp;", " ")
    tempStr = Replace(tempStr, "&lt;", "<")
    tempStr = Replace(tempStr, "&gt;", ">")
    tempStr = Replace(tempStr, "&quot;", Chr(34))
    tempStr = Replace(tempStr, "&apos;", "'")
    tempStr = Replace(tempStr, "&amp;", "&")
    tempStr = Replace(tempStr, "&ndash;", "–")
    tempStr = Replace(tempStr, "&#252;", "ü")
    tempStr = Replace(tempStr, "&deg;", "°")
    tempStr = Replace(tempStr, "&auml;", "ä")
    tempStr = Replace(tempStr, "&uuml;", "ü")
    tempStr = Replace(tempStr, "&rsquo;", "’")

    decodeEnt = tempStr 'Return modified string
End Function
```

Is there a quicker way of performing that operation? Something that modifies the data all at once in the rng.Areas array perhaps? Speed is key for this project, but I'm out of ideas in this case.

Thanks

**EDIT:** To further clarify about the project. It imports an XML file from an API of another tool and saves it into a table in Excel. I have other code that refreshes the connection, appends all data from the XML (new and old). Once the refresh process is complete it begins the data modification which include fixing the HTML/XML entities in the cells and fixing the format for dates. After the modifications are done, , it removes duplicate rows (since there is no way of adding only new data when doing a refresh).

Hope this clears up any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the following would be much faster (doing all cells at once):

```
Sub test()
    Dim replaceThis()
    Dim withThis()
    replaceThis = Array("&lt;", "&gt;") ' etc
    withThis = Array("<", ">") ' etc

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = LBound(replaceThis) To UBound(replaceThis)
      'MsgBox "replacing " & replaceThis(i) & " with " & withThis(i)
      Range("A1:A5").Replace What:=replaceThis(i), Replacement:=withThis(i), _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note - you will want to create an array containing all your substitutions, and I hard coded the range: you need to make that variable.  But seeing your code, I think you can figure it out from here.

Comment: Thank you for this. Do you happen to know how I can find the elapsed time a piece of code takes to run in VBA?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198409/how-do-you-test-running-time-of-vba-code

Comment: @Mo2 - did this make a difference for you?

Answer (score 1):

there is a replace function for ranges which may be faster.

for general performance tips (especially ScreenUpdating, Calculation and "Read/Write Large Blocks of Cells in a Single Operation"):

http://blogs.office.com/2009/03/12/excel-vba-performance-coding-best-practices/

(In my experience the main things that help are deactivating Application.ScreenUpdating, deactivating Application.Calculation or Read/Write Large Blocks of Cells in a Single Operation)

Comment: Thank you for that link. I have a few questions. **1.** Does turning off Application.EnableEvents actually make a difference in speed? I'm not using any events in my code as far as I'm aware (unless running code when the workbook opens is considered an event?). **2.** I'm guessing the range replace function you  mentioned was the one Floris mentioned in his answer? **3.** I don't seem to understand what ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks does. I read the link that was in the article, but I'm still confused on what it exactly does when it's set to True.

Comment: 1. I don't think it will do much (the article states "I learned that some desktop search tools implement event listeners") 2. Yes 3. It prevents Excel if a text line cant be displayed fully in one row to split it in differnt rows

Comment: 3. Isn't that just the word wrap option? If not, then what is the character limit?

Comment: Ok i was wrong, i thought it was wordwrap (didn't remember the word for it). Not totally sure myself.

Comment: I see. Well I think I'll just keep it off to be on the safe side then.