# How can I use data from timing how long functions take to complete to improve the way I construct those functions (VBA)?

Tags: excel, vba, recursion, iteration, automated-tests

Sometimes I have two options for solving a problem - I can do it recursively or iteratively. I know that recursive can often be faster for smaller operations, whilst iteration starts to get faster as the number of times your have to repeat an operation increases. . To test this, I used the code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198409/how-do-you-test-running-time-of-vba-code) to create a timer class, `cTimer`, and recorded how long it took to complete reversing a string with two different functions - one which was iterative, the other recursive: basically I wanted to find out at what point I should switch from using an iterative to a recursive function if I know, for instance, that I could choose between iteratively or recursively reversing a string `str`, and that `Len(str)` is likely to be `>40`.

```
Sub TimeReverse()

Dim strA As String, tStamp As cTimer, i As Long

strA = ""

For i = 1 To 1000
    strA = strA + RandomChar

    Sheets(1).Range("a1").Offset(i, 0).Value = i

    Set tStamp = New cTimer

    Call tStamp.StartCounter
    Call InvertString(strA)
    Sheets(1).Range("b1").Offset(i, 0).Value = CStr(tStamp.TimeElapsed)

    Set tStamp = Nothing

    Set tStamp = New cTimer

    Call tStamp.StartCounter
    Call ReverseString(strA)
    Sheets(1).Range("C1").Offset(i, 0).Value = CStr(tStamp.TimeElapsed)

    Set tStamp = Nothing

    Sheets(1).Range("e1").Offset(i, 0).Value = "=SUM(C" & i + 1 & "-C2)"
Next i

End Sub


Public Function InvertString(str As String) As String

Dim str1, str2, str3, midChar As String, i, x, z As Long

If Len(str) Mod 2 = 0 Then
    str3 = " "
    x = 1
    For i = 1 To (Len(str) / 2)
        str1 = Mid(str, i, 1)
        str2 = Mid(str, (Len(str) - (i - 1)), 1)
        str3 = Mid(str3, 1, x) & str2 & str1 & Mid(str3, (Len(str3) - (x - 1)), x)
        x = x + 1
    Next i

    InvertString = str3
Else

    z = (Int(Len(str) / 2) + 1)
    midChar = Mid(str, z, 1)
    str3 = " "
    x = 1
    For i = 1 To (Len(str) / 2)
        str1 = Mid(str, i, 1)
        str2 = Mid(str, (Len(str) - (i - 1)), 1)
        str3 = Mid(str3, 1, x) & str2 & str1 & Mid(str3, (Len(str3) - (x - 1)), x)
        x = x + 1
    Next i

    InvertString = Mid(str3, 1, z) & midChar & Mid(str3, (z + 1), z)
End If

End Function


Public Function ReverseString(ByVal str As String) As String
'Recursively reverse a string

    If Len(str) <= 1 Then
        ReverseString = str
    Else
        ReverseString = ReverseString(Mid(str, 2, Len(str))) + Mid(str, 1, 1)
    End If

End Function

Private Function RandomChar() As String

Dim b As Integer, t As Integer

b = 32
t = 126

RandomChar = Chr(Int((t + 1 - b) * Rnd + b))

End Function
```

I understand that these functions may not be the fastest way to complete the task - and, of course, there is a built in reverse string operator in VBA (which I chose not to use because I wanted to understand the structure of the functions I was comparing)

I converted the output into a chart:

[image: Chart comparing iteration and recursion]

What I want to ask is "what explains the sharp spikes for some function calls?" It looks like sometimes the spikes seem to occur in both the recursive and iterative procedures for the same string, but (on the left hand side at least) the spike is usually noticeably smaller in the iterative line (although I must admit I haven't checked to see if the proportional difference from base is the same for both lines). But sometimes they are not aligned at all. Is it that some characters are harder to process, or that some background activity is delaying the function (which would explains shared peaks I guess), and, if it is background activity, how come the spikes are not pretty much always aligned? For instance, towards the right hand-side of the chart, there are some pretty massive spikes in the iterative process that don't seem to be shared by the recursive to nearly the same extent. Is it because these functions are now running for so long that background activity has a greater variation in effect upon the two functions in that test loop? What I'm particularly interested in is whether it's something to do with the way I have written these functions? How can I work out from this sort of data how I can smooth out and improve the operation of my functions? Or do I need to rethink how/the purpose for which I gather my data?

Comment: Your computer does lots of other stuff all the time, besides running your VBA, so I wouldn't focus on spikes from timings run for single iterations of any specific function.  Rather than timing a single pass through a function, you will get more "representative" (and less-spiky) data if you run each one in a loop for (say) 1000 or more iterations and divide the total time by the number of runs.  Then do that a few times and average those results. If you really suspect that some strings take longer to process than others, then log the strings as well as the timings, and you can test that out.

Comment: I agree with @Tim Williams... you will need to accept the fact that unless you take great pains to lock down your test environment, there will always be hidden resource usage from many of the tasks. Using Task Manager can give a general idea of some of the I/O, CPU, Network and memory usage that goes on. If you are really curious, then you can look into things like Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process, and GetTcpStatistics, and others...

Comment: I am quite curious, tbh, so thank you both for your input. I was unclear in referring to background activity - I meant the general background stuff that goes on on you computer. So, at about 525 - 541, peaks occur consistently in the recursive, but not the iterative process. I guess this could just be a product of "randomness". How would I create a Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process class in VBA? Or would I have to use VB.Net or a suitable programming language that isn't already built in to standard workplace software suites like Microsoft office?