# High resolution timer/code run time -> overhead?

Tags: performance, vba, excel, runtime

I'm trying to find my Code run time using a high resolution timer, I've noticed that the timer has inconsistent results and I would like to find out why this is.

I found this article
[How do you test running time of VBA code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198409/how-do-you-test-running-time-of-vba-code)
and have implemented the top answer, I tried using it to find the run time of several functions and noticed that the results changed fairly drastically.

To see if this was a fault of the timer, i made a function where I just started and stopped the timer.

```
Public Sub test_ctimer()
    Dim results(0 To 4) As Double
    Dim t As CTimer: Set t = New CTimer
    Dim i As Integer

    'Removes msg box overhead
    MsgBox "about to start"

    For i = 0 To 4
        t.StartCounter
        results(i) = t.TimeElapsed

    Next i

    For i = 0 To 4
        MsgBox results(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

The first measurement takes significantly more time (~ 1 magnitude greater) than any of the following measurements. Does anyone know why this is?

Below is the ctimer code from [How do you test running time of VBA code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198409/how-do-you-test-running-time-of-vba-code)

```
Option Explicit

Private Type LARGE_INTEGER
    lowpart As Long
    highpart As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function QueryPerformanceCounter Lib "kernel32" (lpPerformanceCount As LARGE_INTEGER) As Long
Private Declare Function QueryPerformanceFrequency Lib "kernel32" (lpFrequency As LARGE_INTEGER) As Long

Private m_CounterStart As LARGE_INTEGER
Private m_CounterEnd As LARGE_INTEGER
Private m_crFrequency As Double

Private Const TWO_32 = 4294967296# ' = 256# * 256# * 256# * 256#

Private Function LI2Double(LI As LARGE_INTEGER) As Double
Dim Low As Double
    Low = LI.lowpart
    If Low < 0 Then
        Low = Low + TWO_32
    End If
    LI2Double = LI.highpart * TWO_32 + Low
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
Dim PerfFrequency As LARGE_INTEGER
    QueryPerformanceFrequency PerfFrequency
    m_crFrequency = LI2Double(PerfFrequency)
End Sub

Public Sub StartCounter()
    QueryPerformanceCounter m_CounterStart
End Sub

Property Get TimeElapsed() As Double
Dim crStart As Double
Dim crStop As Double
    QueryPerformanceCounter m_CounterEnd
    crStart = LI2Double(m_CounterStart)
    crStop = LI2Double(m_CounterEnd)
    TimeElapsed = 1000# * (crStop - crStart) / m_crFrequency
End Property
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked class is not great. There is an overhead associated with calling QueryPerformanceCounter it and that overhead should be determined first then used to adjust the subsequent calls. *This would explain all results being slightly slower than expected*, **however it does not explain the first one being substantially slower**. Anyway, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172338 describes an approach to adjust for it. The class I have implemented I do not have access to at this time so I cannot post the relevant parts.

Also for a read unrelated to your specific issue, but related to Timings on Windows in general, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dn553408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx is interesting.

As a workaround in the meantime, add a call to start then stop in the Class_Initialize.

This is not really an answer at all - more of an extended comment - so I will edit it if I ever find a conclusive reason ;)

To reiterate to those upvoting: I cannot explain the reason for the results the OP is querying. I hypothesise it is to do with the VBA interpreter (i.e. close to a JIT'er) but I cannot evidence either way. My commentary above is related to the functions the OP is using but are probably non sequitur.

Comment: I think the first one is actually substantially faster

Comment: @Alter oh whoops. I didnt notice the E-4 bit ;). Hmm, that is very interesting. That ruins my interpreter idea :D

Comment: @Alter can you run it a few times and store the results then output them (e.g. into an `Dim results(0 to 4)...t.StartCounter:results(0) = t.TimeElapsed` kind of thing. Just trying to narrow down possible reasons. (random idea: On the first call it has been instantiated and has been 'accessed' recently through the initialisation. The msgbox, resulting in a lot of complex calls behind the scenes, could push it back to the heap).

Comment: I just tried it as you suggested, running the msgbox in a separate loop in case it interfered. It looks like it did. the results are much closer but still significantly different. the first results is still ~8.4E-4, but now the following results are ~4.27E-3 and occasionally 0...

Comment: @Alter final idea: early bind (so `Dim t As CTimer: Set t = New CTimer` then do something else e.g. `MsgBox "about to start"`) then carry on with the rest in a seperate loop. Again, I am just approaching this from a practical perspective as this is beyond my basic understanding of how VBA is actually run, let alone how the kernel works.

Comment: good idea, interesting results. The first result is now significantly greater (~an order of magnitude) than the following results. I guess this makes your interpreter idea valid again ;)

Comment: @Alter i think what it really means is it is as much a mystery to me as the virgin birth...