# VBA split array with delimiter without loops

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, delimiter

So I'm trying to split an array without using any loops.
`xData` is an variant that stores data from a csv file, each row in the csv file contains ID;value where each row is then placed into the array.

`dData.setNameArray` and `dData.setDataArray` is a custom type object that stores sorted data for later use.

With loops I got:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To UBound(xData)
    dData.setNameArray = Split(xData(i), ";")(0)
    dData.setDataArray = Split(xData(i), ";")(1)
Next i
```

But due to high amount of data I want to avoid this. I thought of removing the `for loop` and split the array as it is but it didn't seem to work.

Is there any other way to do this so I can avoid using loops? I found [Manipulating arrays without loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32272888/manipulating-arrays-without-loops) where the first answer seems to be in the right direction. But i'm not 100% sure how to use it (if it could be a way to do it).

Comment: split it into a tmp variant type var and pull the data from there on each iteration. still a loop but less calculation. btw, what's setNameArray and setDataArray ? some sort of custom class method? ftm, what's xdata?

Comment: Another method:  write the array to a worksheet range (one step); split using the `.TextToColumns` method.  Then read it back into a variant array (also done with a single step).

Comment: @Jeeped Sorry if I was a bit unclear. setNameArray and setDataArray are custom data types that stores the data for later use. and xData are an array that holds information from a csv file. In the csv file each row of data is stored as ID;Value.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld That sounds like it would have a higher time complexity than a normal for loop?

Comment: Set up a timer so you can measure it.  Be sure to use hidden sheets, and turn off screen updating.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I will try to come up with some kind of timer. The screen updating and hidden sheets are all fixed but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: A hi res timer is discussed [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939806/high-resolution-timer-code-run-time-overhead)

Comment: Your going to need to loop. There is no need for split() - particularly twice! - use instr() to locale the ; then left()/right() to get the two values

Answer (score 1):

I think the most efficient way of doing this will be as follows. Notice the use of `Long` instead of `Integer`

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To UBound(xData)
    Dim sa() As String
    sa = Split(xData(i), ";")
    dData.setNameArray = sa(0)
    dData.setDataArray = sa(1)
Next i
```

Comment: It splits the string once rather than twice