# VBA String Spaces: Preferred Method?

Tags: string, vba, concatenation, space

When concatenating strings, there are multiple valid methods of inserting spaces.

**Space Function:**

```
Print "A" & Space(1) & "B"
A B
```

**VS**

**Quotes:**

```
Print "A" & " " & "B"
A B
```

**VS**

**Chr:**

```
Print "A" & Chr(32) & "B"
A B
```

---

All three methods yield the same result.  The only place where I found Space beneficial was when using a variable for the number of spaces.

```
Space( <expression of number - len(var)> )
```

Can anyone provide any insight on why one method is better than another?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they all come down to the same thing when compiled; they only are different representations. For example, " " is a string (list of caracters containing only one space); whereas Chr(32) is the Char representation of a space.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As suggested, they all yield the same result when compiled.  There might be situational benefit such as:

1) `Space()` - Good when multiple space is needed.
***Space(100)*** is better than ***chr(32) & chr(32) & chr(32) & ...***

2) `" "` - Visual expression that is easy to understand, esp for new vba learner
EDIT: Also faster than a method call, thanks to  Blackhawk to point out

3) `chr()` - character expression that could be used to print particular character to say a text file.  E.g. printing ***Enter/Return*** with ***chr(10)***.  I don't see any obvious benefit for print space however

Comment: @RHDxSPAWNx, If all you're doing is writing an immediate string value with a few spaces, "A B" makes the most sense - VBA is going to parse the code anyway, so a few extra spaces in code is probably faster than a method call such as `space()` or `chr()`.  `Space()` is often used to pre-allocate memory in a string for use as a buffer, for example in Windows API calls.  `Chr()` is generally used, as Alex implies, for getting nonprintable characters into a string, such as CR or LF.  I've used it to match non-breaking spaces in webpage text, chr(160).

Answer (score 2):

Using a string literal should be the *fastest* of the bunch because the other two are *functions*. As you pointed out, it's easy to understand, but as [@Alex pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26595609/3198973) `Space()` is definitely better when you need more than a single space. I would always prefer the literal or `space()` over `chr(32)`. `chr(32)` is pretty obscure for the maintainer to grok.

There is another option you didn't consider though. Creating a constant.

```
Const space As String = " "
```

This has all of the readability of `space(1)` with the performance of the literal `" "`. As an added benefit, there is only truly one instance of the constant in memory, where as the literal will show up  once for each instance.

---

If you do decide to use `chr(32)`, it would be beneficial to use to the string version of it: `chr$(32)`. The regular version returns a variant, whereas the string version returns a string. Variants have some extra overhead that can be avoided here.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a performance difference?  You can test it yourself!  See the [the code at this answer related to the performance counters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198409/how-do-you-test-running-time-of-vba-code) to get a useful VBA timer class.

Here's an example of this type of timing in (Excel-ish) VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DoTimings()
    Dim oTimer As New CTimer
    Dim fTimer(3) As Double

    Dim iiter As Long
    Const ITERATIONS As Long = 10000

    oTimer.StartCounter
    For iiter = 1 To ITERATIONS
        Debug.Print "A" & Space(1) & "B"
    Next
    fTimer(1) = oTimer.TimeElapsed

    oTimer.StartCounter
    For iiter = 1 To ITERATIONS
        Debug.Print "A" & " " & "B"
    Next
    fTimer(2) = oTimer.TimeElapsed

    oTimer.StartCounter
    For iiter = 1 To ITERATIONS
        Debug.Print "A" & Chr(32) & "B"
    Next
    fTimer(3) = oTimer.TimeElapsed

    Range("A1").Value = "Spaces: "
    Range("B1").Value = fTimer(1)
    Range("A2").Value = "Quotes: "
    Range("B2").Value = fTimer(2)
    Range("A3").Value = "Chr: "
    Range("B3").Value = fTimer(3)

End Sub
```

When I run that on my machine, the differences are negligible or dominated by other factors (most notably the I/O to whatever you are printing to).  So it is pretty safe to say that there isn't any obvious performance difference, and you can use whatever makes the most sense from a maintainability perspective.

Comment: This won't work without the `CTimer` class, whatever that is.

Comment: Yes, @RubberDuck... That code is available at the link in the post:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198409/how-do-you-test-running-time-of-vba-code