Adding an invisible character to a text string
I want to add an invisible character to a text string.
Dim myString As String
myString = "United States"

The following codes are not ok because the following codes separate the string into two parts. I want to keep the string in one part.
myString = "United" & " " & "States"
myString = "United" & Space(1) & "States"
myString = "United" & Chr(32) & "States"
myString = "United" & Chr(160) & "States"

There must be a character between United and States, but that character must be invisible, and it must take up space.
What character should I put in the following string instead of the question mark?
 myString = "United?States"


This seems to be the common methods for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26595609/8382028... I'm not sure what you mean by "invisible" character, can you elaborate please? A space value is a space value

What's your next step to use the string with invisible chars?

Is it vba or VB.Net? If it's VB.Net, strings (and literals) are already unicode, and you can just include the character you want as part of the literal.

If you want to start out with one string that you type in, myString = "United?States".Replace("?"c, ChrW(8203)) might do.

You need to use a zero-width space, . Try:
myString = "United" & ChrW(8203) & "States"

ChrW() is the Unicode version  of Chr() (which is ASCII). Note that if your implementation doesn't support Unicode, this won't work because ASCII doesn't have a ZWSP character.

Rather than ChrW, which is a VB6 holdover, it would be "more correct" from a .NET perspective to use Convert.ToChar.

Use Alt+0160, either use the Character Map, or hold the Alt key and type 0160 on the number pad.
Result:
United͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏ States

In VB.Net:
Dim myString As String
myString = "United States"

Or as char to add to strings:
    Dim myString As String
    myString = "United" & Chr(160) & "States"


this does exactly what you want ,the vb code has c alt +0160 in it text, you can also replace white spaces with it

i think you want only the number see my changed answer
