# Access dynamic query - Better to build one conditional SQL query or multiple queries with VBA?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a Microsoft Access 2010 form with dropboxes and a checkbox which represent certain parameters. I need to run a query with conditions based on these parameters. It should also be a possibility for no criteria from the dropdown boxes and checkbox in order to pull all data.

I have two working ways of implementing this:

1. I build a query with `IIf` statements in the `WHERE` clause, nesting statements until I have accounted for every combination of criteria. I reference the criteria in the SQL logic by using `Forms!frmMyFrm!checkbox1` for example or by using a function `FormFieldValue(formName,fieldName)` which returns the value of a control with the input of the form and control name (This is because of previous issues). I set this query to run with the press of the form's button.
2. I set a vba sub to run with the press of the button. I check the conditions and set the query SQL to a predetermined SQL string based on the control criteria (referenced in the same way as the previous method). This also involves many `If...Else` statements, but is a little easier to read than a giant query.

What is the preferred method? Which is more efficient?

Comment: I prefer the most efficient method.  I determine that by trying both.

Comment: @DanBracuk My current solution involves a combination of both methods, actually, which works best for me for various reasons. I was attempting to see if there's any more technical reason for one over the other, as well as providing a place for others who may have this question (but have not necessarily put as much effort into researching it) to go.

Comment: I wonder if JET/ACE goes to check the form each time a tuple is tested against the WHERE [field] = FormValue... 
I would stick to the VBA on this one and comment liberally throughout your code.

Comment: I had thought of that originally too, but you would think that the time for a query within access to get something from a form, wouldn't be much longer than for VBA to go and get something from a form.  Hard to say really perhaps ZX9 can come back in the future and let us know once they run into larger queries. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you would find one way is more efficient over the other, at least not noticeably.  For the most part it is simply personal preference.

I generally use VBA and check the value of each dropdown/checkbox and build pieces of the SQL query then put together at the end.  The issue that you may run into with this method though is that if you have a large number of dropdowns and checkboxes the code is easy to get "lost" in.

If time to run is very key though you could always use some of the tips [How do you test running time of VBA code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198409/how-do-you-test-running-time-of-vba-code) to see which way is faster.

Comment: My initial testing indicates the difference is minimal, as you predicted. However, I will (eventually) continue testing as some of my queries reference a substantial amount of information and the time required may be significant.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of experimentation, and [a bit of new information indicating having a pre-built query is faster than having SQL compiled in VBA](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-access/query-or-sql-run-from-vba/1f200146-5f24-4599-b3a1-2c5b55c92616), the most efficient and **clear** solution in the context of Microsoft Access is to build and save a number of dependent queries beforehand.

Essentially, build a string of queries each with an `IIf` dependent on a different criterium. Then you only need to run the final query. The only case where you would have to incorporate a VBA `If...Else` is if you need to query something more complicated than `SELECT...WHERE(IIf(...))`.

This has a few advantages:

1. The SQL is already compiled in the saved query, speeding things up.
2. No more getting lost in code:

   - There is no giant, *nearly-impossible-to-edit* query with way too many `IIf`s.
   - The minimal VBA code is even easier to follow.
3. At least for me, who's not an expert in SQL, it's convenient that I can often use the MS Access visual query builder for each part.