# Excel vba Application.screenupdating vs Application.visible

Tags: performance, excel, vba

I have a vba code that copies certain cells from another excel sheet to active excel sheet. I want the work to complete faster.

So does setting `Application.ScreenUpdating` to false speed up the task better than changing `Application.screenupdating/Application.visible` to hidden or do both?

Answer (score 5):

I have no direct answer to your question; but I think that setting `Application.visible` to `false` will not enhance the performance; I prefer to use the following code:

```
Public Sub YK_Start()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End Sub

Public Sub YK_End()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

usage example:

```
Sub LoopExample()
    Dim Cell As Range
    Call YK_Start
        Columns("B:F").ClearContents
        For Each Cell In Range("A1:A100000")
            Cell.Offset(, 1) = Cell.Value + 1
            Cell.Offset(, 2) = Cell.Value + 2
            Cell.Offset(, 3) = Cell.Value + 3
            Cell.Offset(, 4) = Cell.Value + 4
            Cell.Offset(, 5) = Cell.Value + 5
        Next Cell
    Call YK_End
End Sub
```

This source code will be executed within`18 seconds` without using `Call YK_Start` and `Call YK_End`; and It will be executed within `10 seconds` using these procedures.

Reference: [www.officena.net](http://www.officena.net/ib/index.php?s=af2d42202bea67f6f8932621acffea4c&showtopic=61587&hl=) : An Arabic Office Forum.
**EDIT #1** 
There are many ways to measure the execution time of your code; I don't know the most accurate one; I only need approximate value; See:
[How do you test running time of VBA code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/198409/992406)
I am using the simplest one:

```
Sub my_test()
Dim t As Single
t = Timer
'code
Call LoopExample
MsgBox Timer - t
End Sub
```

Comment: How did you measure the run times? Is there somewhere in the excel application that I can find the runtime of my code?

Comment: @AdityaGuru: I modified my answer; please see **EDIT #1**

Answer (score 3):

> Which one(/both) of Application.screenupdating/Application.visible should I set as false?
>
> **Please provide reasons for your answers.**

It really depends on what you want to do. Let me explain.

**Purpose**

`Application.visible` is used when you do not want the user to see the application. Whether the application is updating or not is immaterial. For example you may have a `Login Userform` displayed and you do not want to show the application till the user enters correct information..

`Application.screenupdating` on the other hand has nothing to do with the visibility of the `Application` per se. It is there to (in simple words) prevent the flicker that you see when the application is being updated.

**Which one should I use?**

1. When the `Screenupdating` is `False`, and `Application.visible` is `True` then the flicker doesn't happen
2. When the `Screenupdating` is `True`, and `Application.visible` is `False` then the flicker happens but you cannot see it as the application is hidden.
3. When the `Screenupdating` is `True`, and `Application.visible` is `True` then the flicker happens and you can see it.
4. When the `Screenupdating` is `False`, and `Application.visible` is `False` then the flicker doesn't happen.

So if you are worried about performance(speed of execution of code) then it is always advisable to switch `Screenupdating` to `False`.

Comment: "When the Screenupdating is True, and Application.visible is False then the flicker happens but you cannot see it as the application is hidden."---I feel as the application is not visible at all, CPU wont allocate resources for the updating at all so we might not even need screenupdating at all. Does this make any sense?

Comment: Why not do the test that houssam mentioned and see it for yourself? :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran a timer on various combinations of the settings. Here's what I found:
Note: All measurements are in milliseconds, but absolute numbers not important*. It's the relative changes I'd like to point out. Feel free to turn into percentages or ratios. (*I favour GetTickCount/GetTickFrequency Win API functions, but it doesn't matter what you choose to use)

Individual Settings:

- Baseline w/ Everything On: 62,182.910
- Everything On (but Visible=False): 60,366.117
- Everything On (but DisplayAlerts=False): 59,639.975
- Everything On (but ScreenUpdating=False): 58,257.545
- Everything On (but Calculation=Manual): 42,605.444
- Everything On (but EnableEvents=False): 17,127.370

Combination of Settings:

- Baseline w/ Everything Off: 8,118.695
- Everything Off (but DisplayAlerts=True): 8,802.461
- Everything Off (but Visible=True): 8,965.122
- Everything Off (but ScreenUpdating=True): 9,912.257
- Everything Off (but Calculation=Automatic): 15,931.297
- Everything Off (but EnableEvents=True): 41,896.063

In short:

- Biggest individual speed-boost comes from EnableEvents=False
- Second biggest individual speed-boost comes from Calculation=Manual
- Third biggest individual speed-boost comes from ScreenUpdating=False
- Even bigger boost comes from combining these three settings

Notable Mentions:

- Application.Visible=False alone has no significant effect (assuming, you're not chasing sub-1 second optimisations... If you are, are you sure VBA is the best tool for the job?). (Personally, I use Application.Visible where Excel is executing a long-running/fragile process and I don't want the user to interfere by touching the sheet)
- DisplayAlerts=False alone has no significant effect, *but* it's job is to reduce the chance of your process being interrupted. (I use this for the same reason as hiding the sheet - it helps avoid interference. If nothing happens that's likely to trigger an alert, this setting will not contribute anything significant. That's unless you're chasing millisecond optimisations.)