# VBA QueryPerformanceCounter Not Working

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to test the execution time differences between data types after looping through 1 million random numbers per data type (integer, double, decimal, and variant). I took this code from the Microsoft Developer website. I am using Excel 2010.

Here is the code:

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub Function1()

    Module Module1

    Declare Function QueryPerformanceCounter Lib "Kernel32" (ByRef X As Long) As Short
    Declare Function QueryPerformanceFrequency Lib "Kernel32" (ByRef X As Long) As Short
    
        Dim Ctr1, Ctr2, Freq As Long
        Dim Acc, I As Integer

        ' Times 100 increment operations by using QueryPerformanceCounter.

        If QueryPerformanceCounter(Ctr1) Then   ' Begin timing.
            For I = 1 To 100                    ' Code is being timed.
                Acc += 1
            Next
            QueryPerformanceCounter (Ctr2)      ' Finish timing.
            Console.WriteLine ("Start Value: " & Ctr1)
            Console.WriteLine ("End Value: " & Ctr2)
            QueryPerformanceFrequency (Freq)
            Console.WriteLine ("QueryPerformanceCounter minimum resolution: 1/" & Freq & " seconds.")
            Console.WriteLine ("100 Increment time: " & (Ctr2 - Ctr1) / Freq & " seconds.")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine ("High-resolution counter not supported.")
        End If
        '
        ' Keep console window open.
        '
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.Write ("Press ENTER to finish ... ")
        Console.Read()

    End Module

    End Sub

    Sub Function1_Int_RandNumCounter()

    Dim Int_RandNum_X As Integer
    Dim Int_RandNum_Y As Integer
    Dim Count As Integer
    
    For Count = 1 To Count = 1000000
        Int_RandNum_X = Rnd(Now) ' Get rnd vals based on Now, built-in VBA property
        Int_RandNum_Y = Rnd(Now)
    Next Count

    '    Call Function1_Dbl_RandNumCounter

End Sub

Sub Function1_Dbl_RandNumCounter()

Dim Dbl_RandNum_X As Double, Dbl_RandNum_Y As Double, Count As Double

    For Count = 1 To Count = 1000000
        Dbl_RandNum_X = Rnd(Now) ' Get rnd vals based on Now, built-in VBA property
        Dbl_RandNum_Y = Rnd(Now)
    Next Count

    Call Function1_Var_RandNumCounter
End Sub
Sub Function1_Var_RandNumCounter()

Dim Var_RandNum_X, Var_RandNum_Y, Count As Variant

    For Count = 1 To Count = 1000000
        Var_RandNum_X = Rnd(Now) ' Get rnd vals based on Now, built-in VBA property
        Var_RandNum_Y = Rnd(Now)
    Next Count

    Call Function1_Dec_RandNumCounter

End Sub
Sub Function1_Dec_RandNumCounter()

Dim Count, Var_RandNum_X, dec_RandNum_X, Var_RandNum_Y, dec_RandNum_Y

dec_RandNum_X = CDec(Var_RandNum_X)
dec_RandNum_Y = CDec(Var_RandNum_Y) ' convert these vals to decimals

    For Count = 1 To Count = 1000000
        dec_RandNum_X = Rnd(Now) ' Get rnd vals based on Now, built-in VBA property
        dec_RandNum_Y = Rnd(Now)
    Next Count

    Call Function2_BarGraph

End Sub
Sub Function2_BarGraph()
'   Put all of these vals in a 2D bar graph
End Sub
```

This code gives me errors such as:

> Compile error:
>
> Only comments may appear after End Sub, End Function, or End Property

EDIT: Here is the improved version of the code, which has no compile errors, but I'm not sure how to integrate the timer into my functions.

```
    Option Explicit

    Private Type LARGE_INTEGER
    lowpart As Long
    highpart As Long
    End Type

    Private Declare Function QueryPerformanceCounter Lib "kernel32" (lpPerformanceCount As LARGE_INTEGER) As Long
Private Declare Function QueryPerformanceFrequency Lib "kernel32" (lpFrequency As LARGE_INTEGER) As Long

Private m_CounterStart As LARGE_INTEGER
Private m_CounterEnd As LARGE_INTEGER
Private m_crFrequency As Double

Private Const TWO_32 = 4294967296# ' = 256# * 256# * 256# * 256#

Private Function LI2Double(LI As LARGE_INTEGER) As Double
Dim Low As Double
    Low = LI.lowpart
    If Low < 0 Then
        Low = Low + TWO_32
    End If
    LI2Double = LI.highpart * TWO_32 + Low
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
Dim PerfFrequency As LARGE_INTEGER
    QueryPerformanceFrequency PerfFrequency
    m_crFrequency = LI2Double(PerfFrequency)
End Sub

Public Sub StartCounter()
    QueryPerformanceCounter m_CounterStart
End Sub

Property Get TimeElapsed() As Double
Dim crStart As Double
Dim crStop As Double
    QueryPerformanceCounter m_CounterEnd
    crStart = LI2Double(m_CounterStart)
    crStop = LI2Double(m_CounterEnd)
    TimeElapsed = 1000# * (crStop - crStart) / m_crFrequency
End Property

Sub Function1_Int_RandNumCounter()

Dim Int_RandNum_X As Integer
Dim Int_RandNum_Y As Integer
Dim Count As Integer
    
    For Count = 1 To Count = 1000000
        Int_RandNum_X = Rnd(Now) ' Get rnd vals based on Now, built-in VBA property
        Int_RandNum_Y = Rnd(Now)
    Next Count

'    Call Function1_Dbl_RandNumCounter

End Sub

Sub Function1_Dbl_RandNumCounter()

Dim Dbl_RandNum_X As Double, Dbl_RandNum_Y As Double, Count As Double

    For Count = 1 To Count = 1000000
        Dbl_RandNum_X = Rnd(Now) ' Get rnd vals based on Now, built-in VBA property
        Dbl_RandNum_Y = Rnd(Now)
    Next Count

    Call Function1_Var_RandNumCounter
End Sub
Sub Function1_Var_RandNumCounter()

Dim Var_RandNum_X, Var_RandNum_Y, Count As Variant

    For Count = 1 To Count = 1000000
        Var_RandNum_X = Rnd(Now) ' Get rnd vals based on Now, built-in VBA property
        Var_RandNum_Y = Rnd(Now)
    Next Count

    Call Function1_Dec_RandNumCounter

End Sub
Sub Function1_Dec_RandNumCounter()

Dim Count, Var_RandNum_X, dec_RandNum_X, Var_RandNum_Y, dec_RandNum_Y

dec_RandNum_X = CDec(Var_RandNum_X)
dec_RandNum_Y = CDec(Var_RandNum_Y) ' convert these vals to decimals

    For Count = 1 To Count = 1000000
        dec_RandNum_X = Rnd(Now) ' Get rnd vals based on Now, built-in VBA property
        dec_RandNum_Y = Rnd(Now)
    Next Count

    Call Function2_BarGraph

End Sub
Sub Function2_BarGraph()
'   Put all of these vals in a 2D bar graph
End Sub
```

EDIT: New VBA code (did I set up this function properly?)

```
Sub Function1_Int_RandNumCounter()
Dim Int_RandNum_X As Integer
Dim Int_RandNum_Y As Integer
Dim Count As Integer
Dim oPM As PerformanceMonitor
Dim Time_Int As Variant

Time_Int = CDec(Time_Int)

Set oPM = New PerformanceMonitor
oPM.StartCounter
For Count = 1 To Count = 1000000
    Int_RandNum_X = Rnd(Now) ' Get rnd vals based on Now, built-in VBA property
    Int_RandNum_Y = Rnd(Now)
Next

Time_Int = oPM.TimeElapsed

'    Call Function1_Dbl_RandNumCounter

End Sub
```

Comment: That's VB.Net code, not VBA.

Comment: FYI your benchmarking types but rarely declare them. `dim a,b as T` only declares `b` as `T`.

Comment: I suggest you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198409/how-do-you-test-running-time-of-vba-code

Comment: @AlexK. I have been telling people the wrong programming language? Oh well.

Comment: @Rory I have added my new version of the code using that timer. Can you tell me how to integrate this timer into my macro? Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasShera Where have you added it? I can't see it... FYI, that linked answer tells you how to use it as a class.

Comment: @Rory the second chunk of code is the new version.

Comment: As I said, the linked thread shows how to use it at the top - add the code to a class module, create an instance, then call its methods as required.

Comment: @Rory do you have any tutorials on how to use this class module and call it? I am learning VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new class module to your project, call it PerformanceMonitor and paste this code from the thread I linked to in my comment into the class:

```
Option Explicit

Private Type LARGE_INTEGER
    lowpart As Long
    highpart As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function QueryPerformanceCounter Lib "kernel32" (lpPerformanceCount As LARGE_INTEGER) As Long
Private Declare Function QueryPerformanceFrequency Lib "kernel32" (lpFrequency As LARGE_INTEGER) As Long

Private m_CounterStart As LARGE_INTEGER
Private m_CounterEnd As LARGE_INTEGER
Private m_crFrequency As Double

Private Const TWO_32 = 4294967296# ' = 256# * 256# * 256# * 256#

Private Function LI2Double(LI As LARGE_INTEGER) As Double
Dim Low As Double
    Low = LI.lowpart
    If Low < 0 Then
        Low = Low + TWO_32
    End If
    LI2Double = LI.highpart * TWO_32 + Low
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Dim PerfFrequency As LARGE_INTEGER

    QueryPerformanceFrequency PerfFrequency
    m_crFrequency = LI2Double(PerfFrequency)
End Sub

Public Sub StartCounter()
    QueryPerformanceCounter m_CounterStart
End Sub

Property Get TimeElapsed() As Double
Dim crStart As Double
Dim crStop As Double
    QueryPerformanceCounter m_CounterEnd
    crStart = LI2Double(m_CounterStart)
    crStop = LI2Double(m_CounterEnd)
    TimeElapsed = 1000# * (crStop - crStart) / m_crFrequency
End Property
```

Now as an example of how to use it, you need to declare and create an instance of the PerformanceMonitor class, then call its `StartCounter` method at the start of the code you want to time, then at the end call its `TimeElapsed` property to see how long it took (in milliseconds). For example:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim n As Long
    Dim oPM As PerformanceMonitor

    Set oPM = New PerformanceMonitor
    oPM.StartCounter
    For n = 1 To 100000
        Debug.Print n
    Next

    MsgBox oPM.TimeElapsed
    Set oPM = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I added that code and adapted my function to include the parts of this timer that need to go in it. How do I declare+create a PerformanceMonitor class and then call TimeElapsed? I think I understand the other parts though.

Comment: I have added my function which replaces your second example function (see above, the third block of code).

Comment: Looks fine - are you having an issue with it?

Comment: that part of the code works perfectly. How do I put this code in a class and then call the method? I am reading this http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/snippets/classes but it seems pretty technical to me and it's intended for beginners.

Comment: That's what you are doing above. If it works, you must have put the code into a class.

Comment: I just meant it doesn't give compile errors. How do I add a class? I can paste all of my code if you want. Thanks for the help.

Comment: In your project, Insert - Class module from the menu, rename it to PerformanceMonitor and then paste the class code in.

Comment: I created a Class module using those instructions. How do I rename it? I'm using Excel 2010.

Comment: I have a class module named PerformanceMonitor now. How do I return to my function modules with all of my macro's code in it? Thanks!

Comment: Just double click one of them in the Project Explorer window.