# Compile error Sub or Function not defined ( VBA )

Tags: vba, compilation

It appeared "Compile error: Sub or Function not defined" when I run the code. I have been finding the solutions but they all did not work. Anyone know please help me. I don't know about coding this is my homework. The professor give this code for us to process the data from our experiment.
Here it my code

```
Function FFTRec(N As Integer, theta As Double, ar() As Double, ai() As Double, tmpr() As Double, tmpi() As Double)
    Dim nh As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim xr, xi, wr, wi, tmp2r(512) As Double, tmp2i(512) As Double

    If N > 1 Then
    nh = N / 2
    For j = 0 To nh - 1
        tmpr(j) = ar(j) + ar(nh + j)
        tmpi(j) = ai(j) + ai(nh + j)
        xr = ar(j) - ar(nh + j)
        xi = ai(j) - ai(nh + j)
        wr = Cos(theta * j)
        wi = Sin(theta * j)
        tmp2r(j) = xr * wr - xi * wi
        tmp2i(j) = xi * wr + xr * wi
    Next j
    Call FFTRec(nh, 2 * theta, tmpr, tmpi, ar, ai)
    Call FFTRec(nh, 2 * theta, tmp2r, tmp2i, ar, ai)
    For j = 0 To nh - 1
        ar(2 * j) = tmpr(j)
        ai(2 * j) = tmpi(j)
        ar(2 * j + 1) = tmp2r(j)
        ai(2 * j + 1) = tmp2i(j)
    Next j
    End If
 End Function
 Public Sub FFT()
    Dim xr(512) As Double, xi(512) As Double, tmpr(512) As Double, tmpi(512) As Double
    Dim pi, wm, theta As Double
    Dim i, Tr, N As Integer
    Dim curStartTime, curEndTime, curFreq As Currency

    i = 0: N = 512: Tr = 6
    pi = WorksheetFunction.pi
    theta = 2 * pi / N

    For i = 1 To N
        xr(i - 1) = Cells(i + Tr - 1, 2): xi(i - 1) = 0
    Next i

    Call QueryPerformanceFreQuency(curFreq)
    Call QueryPerformanceCounter(curStartTime)

    Call FFTRec(N, theta, xr, xi, tmpr, tmpi)

    Call QueryPerformanceCounter(curEndTime)
    Cells(1, 9) = "Processing Time " & CStr((curEndTime - curStartTime) / curFreq) & " Second"

    Cells(Tr - 1, 9) = "xr(i)_FFT": Cells(Tr - 1, 10) = "xi(i)_FFT": Cells(Tr - 1, 11) = "P_FFT"
    For i = 0 To N - 1
        Cells(i + Tr, 9) = xr(i)
     Cells(i + Tr, 10) = xi(i)
    Cells(i + Tr, 11) = Sqr(xr(i) ^ 2 + xi(i) ^ 2)
    Next i
 End Sub
```

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DV2GN.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JTiA.png)

By the way I am not a native speaker.

Thank you.

Comment: If you keep calling FFTRec from within FFTRec with no conditional exit, aren't you going into an infinite loop? You also don't call functions; they return a value.

Answer (score 0):

The function `QueryPerformanceFrequency` is not defined. You need to define it somewhere. I think this should fix it. There is a code present [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31387007/3625350) that you can try.

Else simply ask your professor to provide the code for definition of `QueryPerformanceFrequency`

Comment: Yes. After I ran the program it marked blue at "QueryperformanceFrequency" .It still doesn't work with the new solution.It appeared "Code error: The code in this project must be updated for use on 64-bit systems. Please review and update Declare statements and then mark them with the PtrSafe attribute.".But Thank you so much.

Comment: @benkyoua There is nothing in your code above that is 64 v 32 dependant as far as I can see. If your code was formatted correctly it would be a lot easier to tell. I am guessing you are referring to an API call that is made somewhere else in the code. Probably in one of your not show calls.

Comment: Yes, I tried to define QueryPerformanceFrequency and added some codes (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383177/vba-queryperformancecounter-not-working/31387007#31387007) into Class modules.

Comment: Private Declare PtrSafe Function  for 64 bit. I am guessing you already did that!

Comment: Yeah, I did but still.Thank you guys.