# Powerpoint Video gets choppy when VBA countdown is running

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint countdown slide that has a looping video. In the note field of the slide is the time the event will begin. The VBA countdown will count down to this time and starts when the mouse over event of the Shape happens on the slide that has the countdown. At the end of the countdown the presentation advances to the next slide. The presentation starts fine and when the slide starts the video starts and other animations function as expected. However, when the countdown starts the video and countdown get choppy. My code seems simple and I'm not sure what is causing the choppiness. Can someone help with where my performance issues are?

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function WaitMessage Lib "user32" () As Long
   
Public Sub Wait(Seconds As Double)
    Dim EndTime As Double
    EndTime = DateTime.Timer + Seconds
    Do
        WaitMessage
        DoEvents
    Loop While DateTime.Timer < EndTime
End Sub
 
Public Sub StartCountdown()
    Dim TimeInSeconds As Integer
    Dim SlideIndex As Integer
    Dim Slide As Slide
    Dim sSlideNote As String
    Dim TextBox As Shape
    Dim StartTime As Date
    Dim EndTime As Date

    ' Set the slide index where you want the countdown timer
    SlideIndex = 1
    
    ' Check if the slide index is valid
    If SlideIndex > 0 And SlideIndex <= ActivePresentation.Slides.count Then
        ' Create or update the countdown timer textbox
        Set Slide = ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideIndex)
        Set TextBox = Slide.Shapes("countdown")
        If TextBox Is Nothing Then
            Set TextBox = Slide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 100, 100, 200, 50)
            TextBox.Name = "CountdownTimer"
        End If
        
        sSlideNote = Slide.NotesPage.Shapes.Placeholders(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text
        ' Replace carriage return characters with a CR + LF so that multiple lines get output correctly
        sSlideNote = Replace(sSlideNote, Chr(13), vbCrLf)
        
        EndTime = Now()
        SecondsToEnd = DateDiff("s", time, TimeValue(sSlideNote))
        EndTime = DateAdd("s", SecondsToEnd, EndTime)
        TextBox.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Format((EndTime - Now()), "nn:ss")
        
        ' Start the countdown
        Do While EndTime > Now()
            TextBox.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Format((EndTime - Now()), "nn:ss")
            Wait 1
            DoEvents ' Allows the slide to update while counting down
        Loop
        
        ' Final Message after countdown timer ends
        TextBox.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Let's Begin"
        ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid slide index."
    End If
End Sub
```

Keep in mind this is running in PowerPoint VBA.

Comment: "Wait" is an Excel function that does not exist in PowerPoint. See this page for alternate PowerPoint pause techniques: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57268161/sleep-wait-timer-in-powerpoint-vba-thats-not-cpu-intensive If changing that doesn't fix the problem, you might try slowing down the rate at which you update the text box..

Comment: The Wait I use is the Exact wait your link refers to. Changing the Wait to 5 seconds the problem still persists each time the text is being updated.

Comment: How about making each section of the countdown a separate function/sub? In this way VBA will be forced to process them before exiting. I did [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76794690/18247317) for copy/paste and it worked (and it has become my standard method for it, I use it also when I am forced to use `.Select` if I have to use something from the ribbon that is unvailable with VBA)