# What is 1 interval in the timer VB (What is 1 interval in normal time)

Tags: vb.net, timer

I am making a program that has a timer inside of it. I want the timer to be able to display milliseconds so I used the timer from the tool bar in VB and I fiddled around with the intervals but I cant get it to measure 1 millisecond.
I have searched around a lot and I could not find anything useful accept one thing called System.Timers.Timer but I cant figure out how to use it. So could someone tell me what number of intervals = 1 millisecond and what System.Timers.Timer is and how to use it.
For help helping me:
In my code the timer adds one to a variable called mili every time it ticks and then displays that in a text box. When mili = 1000 it adds one to a variable called seconds and when seconds hits 60 it does the same for minuets.

```
Private Sub Timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer.Tick
mili = mili + 1
If mili = 1000 Then
mili = 0
second = second + 1
lblsec.Text = second
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are .NET timers limited to 15 ms resolution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744032/why-are-net-timers-limited-to-15-ms-resolution)

Comment: Take a look at this answer for information on a high resolution timer if you need it [How do you test running time of VBA code?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/198702/4717755)