# How to Identify Substring in a string without spaces

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to check whether the substring `PROD` is present in the string`Today's proDuction` and return values as True or False.

Here the expected answer is true.

How can I do this in VBA

Comment: If you want to find out if a substring is **In** another **Str**ing use **InStr**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My original answer:

```
Instr(Ucase("Today's proDuction"), "PROD") > 0
```

or

```
Instr(Lcase("Today's proDuction"), "prod") > 0
```

EDIT: 
In light of @GSerg's comment below and the answer from @KDavis, I thought it would be worth investigating and comparing different approaches. Interestingly, the results are not what I had expected. Here is my test code:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub A()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim res As Boolean

    '// Timer class courtesy of @Mike Woodhouse here:
    '// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198409/how-do-you-test-running-time-of-vba-code
    Dim tt As cTimer

    Set tt = New cTimer

    '// First test using UCASE to convert text with default comparison mode
    Debug.Print "A " & Now();

    tt.StartCounter

    For i = 1 To 10000000
        '// Need to state binary compare explicitly to override Option Compare Text above
        res = InStr(1, UCase("Today's proDuction"), "PROD", vbBinaryCompare) > 0
    Next i

    Debug.Print " [" & tt.TimeElapsed & "]"


    '// Second test using vbTextCompare comparison mode and implicit type conversion
    Debug.Print "B " & Now();

    tt.StartCounter

    For i = 1 To 10000000
        res = InStr(1, "Today's proDuction", "PROD", vbTextCompare)
    Next i


    Debug.Print " [" & tt.TimeElapsed & "]"


    '// Third test using vbTextCompare comparison mode and explicit test to convert to boolean
    Debug.Print "C " & Now();

    tt.StartCounter

    For i = 1 To 10000000
        res = InStr(1, "Today's proDuction", "PROD", vbTextCompare) > 0
    Next i

    Debug.Print " [" & tt.TimeElapsed & "]"



    '// Fourth test using vbTextCompare comparison mode and explicit type conversion
    Debug.Print "D " & Now();

    tt.StartCounter

    For i = 1 To 10000000
        res = CBool(InStr(1, "Today's proDuction", "PROD", vbTextCompare))
    Next i

    Debug.Print " [" & tt.TimeElapsed & "]"

    '// Fourth test using like
    Debug.Print "E " & Now();

    tt.StartCounter

    For i = 1 To 10000000
        res = "Today's proDuction" Like "*PROD*"
    Next i

    Debug.Print " [" & tt.TimeElapsed & "]"
End Sub
```

Here is a typical result, pretty consistent across a number of test runs:

```
A 28/02/2018 14:36:29 [3479.85848592479]
B 28/02/2018 14:36:33 [5145.24250798252]
C 28/02/2018 14:36:38 [5159.0118225338]
D 28/02/2018 14:36:43 [6627.32650697809]
E 28/02/2018 14:36:50 [6042.61252265476]
```

So, it appears that converting to upper case and then using INSTR with the default comparison mode operates detectably faster than both using the vbTextCompare comparison mode of InStr, and using `Like` syntax with wildcards.

In most cases, of course, the difference in performance is not likely to be noticeable.

Comment: `InStr` supports comparison modes. Using either `UCase` or `LCase` is wrong.

Comment: Yes, converting to upper case is faster [because it's wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/234751/11683). If you accept that your code is allowed to be wrong, then you can push it even further and make it infinitely fast by simply doing nothing and returning.

Comment: Hmmm. @GSerg Yes, point taken, you are right that this might not work in some locales. But accepting code that is wrong in some circumstances is _not_ equivalent to accepting code that is always wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Like`.

```
Sub testString()

    Dim myStr As String

    myStr = "Today's production"

    MsgBox myStr Like "*prod*"

End Sub
```

> This would require the usage of `Option Compare Text` at the top of your module **if you are wanting case-insensitive results**, as the default compare method is to compare Binary (*case-sensitive*).

An easier method as suggested by [Jeeped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49006963/how-to-identify-substring-in-a-string-without-spaces/49007031#comment85018492_49006963) would be best if you do not want to check for case-sensitivity.

```
Sub testString()

    Dim myStr As String

    myStr = "Today's proDuction"

    MsgBox InStr(1, myStr, "prod", vbTextCompare) > 0

End Sub
```