# Excel File Dialog extremely slow

Tags: excel, vba

Good morning. I have the following code in an Excel worksheet. It's an ActiveX control button which runs the following when pressed..

```
Private Sub importSheetPathbtn_Click()
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog 'folder dialog box
    Dim strPath As String 'holds the path/filename
    Dim objFso 'create object to set as filesystem object in order to use folderexists... dumb
    
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) 'sets the filedialog variable as folder picker object
    Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 'creates the object
    
    'set parameters
    With fd
        'checks to see if master path has content
        If masterPathlbl.Caption <> "" Then
            'if master path has content checks to see if the content points to an existing directory
            If objFso.FolderExists(masterPathlbl.Caption) Then
                .InitialFileName = masterPathlbl.Caption 'if master path points to an existing directory, opens folder dialog box in that directory
            Else
                .InitialFileName = "C:\" 'if master path content is not an existing directory then opens to C drive
            End If
        Else 'if master path has no content, opens to C drive
            .InitialFileName = "C:\"
        End If
        
        
        If .Show = -1 Then 'if ok is pressed
            strPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
    
    'if a valid path was seletced then places it into the master path
    If objFso.FolderExists(strPath) Then
        masterPathlbl.Caption = strPath 'places the selected folder into the master path label
    End If
    
    'clears objects
    'fd = Nothing
    'objFso = Nothing
End Sub
```

All it is doing is taking the folder the user selects and placing its path into a label as a caption. It works, but takes a good 10-15 seconds.

On a side note, I am also wondering how to properly close the objects that are created?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks for your time.

Comment: I can't see why that should take that long, but wouldn't `Dir` be less overhead than FSO?

Comment: I am not too familiar with VBA, can you elaborate how you'd use Dir?

Comment: `If Dir(masterPathlbl.Caption, vbdirectory) <> vbnullstring then` rather than all the `objFso.FolderExists` calls

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I couldn't find a better way to do that online. I also changed "fd = nothing" to "Set fd = nothing", not sure why I didn't try that before. But back to the main issue, the lag is still there.

Comment: Using network locations or local?

Comment: Local, but the finished sheet will use network locations. I should probably mention I'm running excel in Windows 10 on a dual boot MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did use TimerBenchmark ([How do you test running time of VBA code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198409/how-do-you-test-running-time-of-vba-code/68406681#68406681), [How do you test running time of VBA code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198409/how-do-you-test-running-time-of-vba-code/68406681#68406681) and [VBA-Benchmark](https://github.com/jonadv/VBA-Benchmark)) and entered three `bm.TrackByName "label"` lines:

```
Sub importSheetPathbtn_Click()
    ...
    ...
    bm.TrackByName "setup till .show"                  'bm ... added
    If .Show = -1 Then 'if ok is pressed
        bm.TrackByName "immediately after .show"       'bm ... added
    ...
    ...
    bm.TrackByName "finish"                            'bm ... added
End Sub
```

As visible in the TimerBenchmark your code needs minimal time:

```
IDnr  Name                     Count  Sum of tics  Percentage  Time sum
0     setup till .show             1           92       0,00%   9200 ns  <--- YOUR CODE
1     immediately after .show      1   38.232.918      99,99%    3,82 s
2     finish                       1        2.677       0,01%    268 us  <--- YOUR CODE
      TOTAL                        3   38.235.687     100,00%    3,82 s

Total time recorded:             3,82 s
```

You have to review your operating system setup to search for the reasons why your windows explorer reacts slowly. There are 100's of possible reasons!

```
'REMARK:
'when using VBA-Benchmark = cBenchmark.bas
'you need to change "QuickSort" with "QuickSortArray"
'in line 720 + 721

If (inLow < tmpHi) Then QuickSortArray vArray, inLow, tmpHi
If (tmpLow < inHi) Then QuickSortArray vArray, tmpLow, inHi

instead of
If (inLow < tmpHi) Then QuickSort vArray, inLow, tmpHi
If (tmpLow < inHi) Then QuickSort vArray, tmpLow, inHi
```

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard of TimerBenchmark. I'm going to mark this as answered since it seems as though it's not the code but my setup. Thanks for your time.