# is there a speed different in Excel index(Match) and xlookup

Tags: excel

I have discovered that there is a function in excel `=XLOOKUP()` this is a nice replacement to doing `=INDEX(range_A,MATCH(value_B,range_B,0))`. Does anyone know if there is a performance difference when you have 50,000 rows or more of data?

Comment: Not sure how to answer this question but it seems interesting.

Comment: Try it and see. Benchmark the (older,simpler,more limited) vlookup while you're at it.

Comment: @Stax - How would you do such a test?

Comment: You can observer CPU usage when you run `XLOOKUP()` over 50000 dataset.

Comment: Simplest: Time all three with a stopwatch. if it happens too quick to be comparable, create a 500,000 dataset, or even all the rows (Approx 1 million). More accurately: you will need to Write VBA code and subtract the start time from the end time, but within Excel this will only give you 1 second granularity (actually, apparently "Timer" is ok to 1/100s. YMMV). Best accuracy (and probably far beyond your needs): https://stackoverflow.com/q/198409/3654325

Comment: @Stax thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I also found this solution which helped be too. https://www.excelcampus.com/functions/vlookup-choose-vs-index-match/
Hey this is the first answer that I have on here can I get some upvotes? ShaneS and Harun24hr what do you think?

Comment: [Here's a good read](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2015/05/11/timing-excel-formula-calculations/) about timing Excel functions

Comment: Vlookup is limited compared to index with match, so it is not a perfect replacement.

Comment: @SolarMike Your right I agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

I did not create 50,000 rows of data but I was able to test it on 10,000. The difference in `=XLOOKUP()` and `=INDEX(range_A,MATCH(value_B,range_B,0))` is virtually the same with in a margin of error. Stax said I should test the `vlookup` to so I did.

Testing on the whole column reference with 10,000 rows.

```
Function      time in sec    formula function
vlookup       0.045          =VLOOKUP(E6,$B:$C,2,FALSE)
index-match   0.044          =INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(E7,$B:$B,0))
xlookup       0.045          =XLOOKUP(E7,B:B,A:A)
```

Testing on only 500 rows and not whole column reference.

```
Function      time in sec    formula function
vlookup       0.047          =VLOOKUP(E6,$B$6:$C$505,2,FALSE)
index-match   0.047          =INDEX($A$6:$A$505,MATCH(E6,$B$6:$B$505,0))
xlookup       0.063          =XLOOKUP(E6,B$6:B$505,A$6:A$505)
```

Comment: Interesting! I would not have thought the first two were so similar. Not surprised the Xlookup is a little slower... it just has much more functionality.