# stuck with Xlookup in vba

Tags: excel, vba, xlookup

hello.

I want to execute the Xlookup function from vba without bothering writing the formula in an excel sheet.
I think have checked every page google could offer me about the problem but I couldn't find satisfying results.

This for exemple return me: "Runtime error 1004: Unable to get the Xlookup property of the worksheetfunction class"

```
Sub searching()

Dim strSearched As String
Dim rngSearch As Range
Dim rngRenurned As Range

strSearched = "FSATA"
Set rngSearch = Sheets("asheet").Range("C:C")
Set rngRenurned = Sheets("asheet").Range("B:B")
MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(strSearched, rngSearch, rngRenurned)

End Sub
```

Could it be a reference problem ? I wanted to collect informations about the [Microsoft learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.vlookup) website but it seem Xlookup dont have any page on it.

Comment: The error means that your lookup failed.

Comment: What version of Excel do you have ?

Comment: XLOOKUP is not available in Excel 2016 and Excel 2019, however, you may come across a situation of using a workbook in Excel 2016 or Excel 2019 with the XLOOKUP function in it created by someone else using a newer version of Excel.. Check [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929)

Comment: [XLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929), only the first hit in Google search. There is a 4th argument whose parameter you can set if no match is found e.g. `.XLookup(strSearched, rngSearch, rngRenurned, "Not found")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you know that your Excel version supports `XLOOKUP`, you still can get the error 1004, if nothing can be found. Two simple things to do about it:

1. Provide a 4th argument as suggested by VBasic2008:

```
MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunctionXLookup(strSearched, rngSearch, rngRenurned, "Not found")
```

2. Ignore the error for that line. Note however that you will see no message box in case nothing is found:

```
On Error Resume Next
MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(strSearched, rngSearch, rngRenurned)
On Error GoTo 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have `XLookUp` then an alternative is INDEX-MATCH. The difference in speed is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72553602/)

```vb
Dim v: v = Application.Match(strSearched, rngSearch.Value, 0)
If Not IsError(v) Then
    MsgBox Application.Index(rngRenurned, v)
Else
    MsgBox "'" & strSearched & "' not found", vbExclamation
End If
```